# TypeScript errors in VSCode: "Cannot write file 'x' because it would overwrite input file."

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code

I'm using TypeScript in VSCode to raise the bar on my JavaScript quality.  However, tsconfig.json keeps throwing errors that it cannot write my .js files.  Specifically:

"Cannot write file 'lib/chart.js' because it would overwrite input file."

I've seen several similar questions here, but they all simply suggest to exclude the .js files.  However, I actually want TypeScript to show me code warnings for those files.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to have TypeScript review my JS files, but not keep throwing errors about not being able to write the input file itself.

Note, that this doesn't happen for all my .js files, just some of them.

Below is my tsconfig.json file.  Note that all my .js files are in the lib folder.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
    },
    "include": [
        "lib"
    ],
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "enable": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Cannot write file 'lib/chart.js' because it would overwrite input file."

Use `outDir` if you are using `allowJs`. TypeScript will take the input `.js` files and put a same named one in the `outDir`.

Comment: Sweet.  Actually after looking at your answer, I just created `"outFile":"out.js"` and the error went away.  Interestingly, I don't see any file actually being created.

Comment: The file is created only when you run `tsc` and not by the on-the-fly checks.